# R sentiment analysis; 'lexicon' not found;

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, lexicon

i am very new to sentiment analysis. I am running the codes based on the tutorial [here](http://varianceexplained.org/r/yelp-sentiment/)

It is using a tidytext package. But I encountered the problem when I run the code

```
AFINN <- sentiments %>%
  filter(lexicon == "AFINN") %>%
  select(word, afinn_score = score)

AFINN
```

The error is as below

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
✖ object 'lexicon' not found
ℹ Input `..1` is `lexicon == "AFINN"`.
```

I guess it is because the lexicon column is not in the sentiments dataframe. Or is the tidytext package changed so that i could not run the code the way that the tutorial ran it? is there any other way to correct the code or run another similar code?

Thank you in advance for your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same tutorial and had to make the following change

```
AFINN <- sentiments %>%
  filter(lexicon == "AFINN") %>%
  select(word, afinn_score = score)
```

becomes

```
AFINN <- get_sentiments("afinn") %>%
  select(word, afinn_score = value)
```

Then the rest of the tutorial worked

Comment: Can you explain why it has to be changed like that?

Comment: sentiments only has the 'bing' lexicon by default and no column for lexicon type anymore. This seems to be due to a licensing issue https://juliasilge.com/blog/sentiment-lexicons/ and the other lexicons need to be downloaded upon request.